# loading third party modules into ui5 without access to a global instance name

Tags: sapui5

I'm struggling of finding a way to include third party libraries into my sapui5 controllers.

While blog posts like this one https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/ describe ways to include libaries like *moment* or *underscore*, such a solution does not apply to modules that do not export a global name.

How can I load browserifed modules (e.g. https://github.com/jameswyse/forecast) in my SAPUI5 application?

Comment: you can achieve this using requirejs, but then it feels like you break the whole sapui import stuff. if you find a proper solution let me know !