# Correctly importing Google Maps API into UI5 Application

Tags: google-maps, sapui5

I'm having trouble determining the best way to import a third party library such as the Google Maps JavaScript API into a UI5 application. I have considered the following methods so far:

- Using a `<script>` tag in `index.html`, such as
  `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key"></script>`
  This works when testing locally but as mentioned in [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/30/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-modules-in-sapui5/) SAP blog post, an app that is launched from the SAP Fiori Launchpad launches via the `Component.js`, not the `index.html`
- That same blog post mentions importing a library via `sap.ui.define`, which is in fact what I'm doing with `moment.js` already in the application, which works. The problem is that the Google Maps API does not expose a global instance name / does not consist of a single JS file which can be imported, and thus this import fails. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444542/loading-third-party-modules-into-ui5-without-access-to-a-global-instance-name) was asked in June last year but did not get answered.
- A comment on that same question mentions using `require.js` to import the Google Maps API. This will likely work but seems like a hack. It feels like there should be some UI5-specific way to do this without having to import yet another third-party library.
- Finally, [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/06/integrate-google-map-with-sapui5-application/) SAP blog post suggests manually creating and appending the Google Maps import `<script>` tag into the DOM once the window has loaded. This also seems like a hack but might be the only way to achieve this for the time being.

Any help determining the correct method of achieving this would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the use case of Google Maps in your application in the first place? In case of displaying a certain location, calculating optimal routes, or performing search, just [opening Google Maps via specific URL parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) might be sufficient which doesn't even require an API key.

Comment: I need to integrate a map into one of the views with custom markers based on user location. I only need the map and marker functionality but it needs to be within the actual UI5 app, not open an external link to Google Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following, which seems to provide the desired results:

```
jQuery.sap.includeScript(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key",
    "includeGoogleMaps",
    function () {
        // Do things
    }
);
```

I found this solution in the following Stack Overflow questions:

- [Using external js libraries in sapui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622034/using-external-js-libraries-in-sapui5)
- [UsingjQuery.sap.includeScript().then() in HCP Firori Launchpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967981/usingjquery-sap-includescript-then-in-hcp-firori-launchpad/38973947#38973947)

If there's anything wrong with the proposed solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would do it like this:

1. Create custom control for map (better from [sap.ui.core.HTML](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.HTML));
2. In `init` method of this control, load GoogleMaps by adding script tag to the page (no load event required here, because page is already loaded when this code executes);
3. In `renderer` of this new control, create a `div` where map will be rendered;
4. HTML Control has **very important** property - "preferDOM", this has to be set to `true`, otherwise, when UI5 rendering cycle happens, GoogleMap will be destroyed and created again which is very bad user experience in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to implement google maps in UI5 apps:

- If you are using SAPUI5: there are controls for generic map integration which you can configure to use google maps as provider:
  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap
  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.vk.MapContainer
- If you are using OpenUI5 you may be interested in this community library that wraps the google API in custom controls:
  https://github.com/jasper07/openui5-googlemaps
- If you are in need of something else, you can inject the JavaScript of google directly as the above poster explained and inject the map into the app but it might not be flexible enough. You can always create a simple custom control rendering an empty div for the map and connect it with the maps API to render the map via google API's.

However, pay attention to the Google TOS, they might require a license to use the maps API productively in your code.

Have Fun,
Michael